# Can I change my edit approval/rejection flag?

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits

I was looking at the suggested edits for a post and I did not think that the changes proposed were encompassing enough to warrant a modification to the post, so I rejected it. After rereading the suggested edit, however, I realized that the edit was valid and I wanted to change my flag to "approve" instead. I saw no option to do so.

Do edits behave like votes in that I am able to alter them for a few seconds after I make my original judgement or are they concrete and there are no options to modify an edit approval/rejection once it's been set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, such an option does not exist. Once you finished reviewing an item, [you cannot change your decision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179612/295232). Don't worry, mistakes like this happen; that's one of the reasons *two* approvals/rejections are necessary for a final verdict on the edit.